# C function that prints pointer of an array?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a c program that prints out pointer of an array here is what i attempted

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArr(int index,char *arr);
char *str[] = {"heyyo","help"};


int main()
{
    //printf(*(str+1)); --Works
    printArr(1,str); //  --No output
    return 0;
}


void  printArr(int index,char *arr){
    printf(*(arr+index));
}
```

Function doesen't work it gives no output as an result

Comment: How do you compile your program? If it's GCC or Clang, add `-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` to your compiler invocation. It will be quite illuminating.

Comment: Just "help" it works if i do printf(*(str+1));

Comment: Note that everytime you write `*(array + index)`, you get the exact same results by using some sugar and writing `array[index]`, which is way clearer.

Comment: @unwind same clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a type mismatch in the code. `str` is a pointer to a char array, while the function takes a pointer to char.

```
test.c:11:16: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘printArr’ from incompatible pointer type
     printArr(1,str); //  --No output
                ^
test.c:4:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 void printArr(int index,char *arr);
```

Comment: Thanks i fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 void  printArr(int index,char **arr){
     printf("%s\n",*(arr+index));
 }
```

Play yourself https://ideone.com/LrNmJk

Comment: What is the meaning of double * in the parameter? (And doesen't work?)

Comment: A pointer to a pointer, e.g. A pointer to an array of character arrays. What you currently have is a pointer to a (possible) char array, which would just be a string.